# How to create Cocoa Touch Framework using Swift language and use it in other Swift projects?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift, frameworks

I've just started to develop iOS app using Swift language, but I noticed we can create a Cocoa Touch Framework to be able reuse in other projects. I've already finished my own framework but I got problem when I was trying to use it in my current project. It seems my project didn't recognize classes in framework although I called `import MyCustomFramework` in files which is using features of framework.

Here is my sample framework structure:

`MyCustomFramework
|--MyCustomFramework.h (I didn't modify this file, it only contains default code same as when creating)
|--TestClass.swift (Define class with public keyword)`

Has anyone got same problem?

Comment: 'MyCustomFramework'created with Objective C?

Comment: @BaSha My own framework was created using Swift also.

Answer (score 0):

When we create ***frameworks*** the most important thing is the ***Access specifiers*** ***private, internal and public***. So we need to ***declare the functions and properties as public*** if we want to access it outside the frameworks!

Comment: I've already put `public` keyword in all classes, but I cannot access these classes from my project.

Comment: So is it giving any error when you import? If not then did you write the class names manually? As some times intellisense does not give its inputs